# select different values from same column in a table and display it under different columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table named "ORDER_HISTORY" where there is a column named "Status".The "Status" column contains different status values for different stores.

My requirement is that I need to fetch the different status values(count) for each store and display these in their corresponding columns.For example: If i have 53(order_cancelled) and 57(order_completed) as two status, and for store number 20 I have two orders with status 57(i.e.order_completed) and one order with status 53(order_cancelled),then i need to display the result(count) in the format as below as:

```
================================================
Store_ID || order_cancelled || order_completed||
------------------------------------------------
20       || 1               || 2              ||
================================================
```

How to write a query that does the above work?

Please help.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no idea on how to separate a single column values and display them as different columns

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT a.Store_ID,b.total as order_completed,c.total as order_completed FROM ORDER_HISTORY a
LEFT OUTER join (select Store_ID,count(*) as total from ORDER_HISTORY where Status=57 group by Store_ID) b on a.Store_ID=b.Store_ID
LEFT OUTER join (select Store_ID,count(*) as total from ORDER_HISTORY where Status=53 group by Store_ID) c on a.Store_ID=c.Store_ID
group by a.Store_ID
```

Comment: Can you suggest another query without using joins as it affects the performance?-@Jeffry Evan

Answer (score 0):

***try this***

SELECT Store_ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(Status) FROM order_history
        WHERE Status = 53) AS order_cancelled,
    (select COUNT(Status)  FROM order_history
        WHERE Status = 57) order_completed
FROM
    clover_source.order_history
   group by Store_ID ;

Comment: the above query is giving me the same count for all the stores

Answer (score 0):

try this:

SELECT        dbo.ORDER_HISTORY.Store_ID, ORDER_HISTORY_Cancelled.order_cancelled, ORDER_HISTORY_completed.order_completed
FROM            dbo.ORDER_HISTORY LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Store_ID, COUNT(Status) AS order_cancelled
                               FROM            dbo.ORDER_HISTORY AS TotalCancelled
                               WHERE        (Status = N'53')
                               GROUP BY Store_ID) AS ORDER_HISTORY_Cancelled ON dbo.ORDER_HISTORY.Store_ID = ORDER_HISTORY_Cancelled.Store_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        Store_ID, COUNT(Status) AS order_completed
                               FROM            dbo.ORDER_HISTORY AS TotalComleted
                               WHERE        (Status = N'57')
                               GROUP BY Store_ID) AS ORDER_HISTORY_completed ON dbo.ORDER_HISTORY.Store_ID = ORDER_HISTORY_completed.Store_ID
GROUP BY dbo.ORDER_HISTORY.Store_ID, ORDER_HISTORY_Cancelled.order_cancelled, ORDER_HISTORY_completed.order_completed

Comment: -Thanks.But could you suggest a query that does not involve joins due to performance factors